# How to Share Android Screenshot dynamically by button click

Tags: android, bitmap, android-appwidget

I am working on an app which requires specifically to take a screenshot of the screen and should be able to share it as a image file. I also need to include a hyperlink as caption to the image for Watsapp and Facebook. 
I am using the below code which share the image of the view. Need more advise on how to include link to the file.

```
XML File for Button to Create a image and Assign to ImageView
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/send_text"
    android:id="@+id/send_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/brands"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Class Code

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    //Get a reference to EditText
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    String msg = editText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(msg);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BeerMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BeerMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, msg);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap b = snap(view.getRootView());
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
    intent.putExtra(BeerMessageActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE, bs.toByteArray());
    /*intent.putExtra(BeerMessageActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE,snap(view));*/
    startActivity(intent);
}
public static Bitmap snap(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Onclick Event on ImageView

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:id="@+id/img_test"
    android:onClick="shareit"/>
```

Code for shareit function

```
public void shareit(View view)
{
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_test);//your layout id

    Bitmap app_snap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SaveImg";
    System.out.println("****FILEPATH **** : " + file_path);



    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/scr.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        System.out.println("****FILEPATH1 **** : " + file_path);
        app_snap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    System.out.println("****FILEPATH2 **** : " + file_path);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("GREC****** "+ e.getMessage());
    }


    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
    sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    startActivity(sharingIntent);
}
```

Please advise if conversion to byte array is required or we can do it without it.
I have got to a place where the above code share a picture. via watsapp/facebook/Google+.